# "X equals Y" vs. "X is equal to Y"

Tags: verbs, expressions, adjectives

What's the subtle difference between *X equals Y* and *X is equal to Y*?

Answer (score 2):

They mean exactly the same thing in mathematics. I prefer *X equals Y* to *X is equal to Y* because the former has less syllables.

Comment: Agreed.  There is no difference in mathematics.  You may choose one or the other in poetry if you want to get it to scan, or make it rhyme or something.

Comment: it may also be wording of the symbol "=" (is equal to) in the second guess

Answer (score 2):

"**X equals Y**" is a bare statement of fact.

"**X is equal to Y**" sounds more like the conclusion to an logic exercise:

> Calculate the value of X, if Y = a, Z = b, and if ..., and if you do ... .
>   Conclusion: X is equal to Y.

Answer (score 2):

In programming, when people read or dictate code, it is common for a spoken "X equals Y" to literally mean "x = y" which is an assignment. "X is equal to Y", prefaced with e.g. "if" or "when" would be unambiguously used to indicate a check for equality, as in "x == y".

In mathematics and regular English, there's no difference. "X is equal to Y" does have a bit more emphasis if you're affirming the fact, though.